# Why is it that the /* on the end of the google link in "manifest.json" doesnt react when i write something into google

Tags: css, json, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

So I am trying to make an extension for google where on google.com and google.com/search etc the background changes right and I got it working for google.com but not /search:

This is the manifest.json file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Simple Google Backgrounds",
    "version": "1.0",
  
    "description": "A simple Extension that makes it so you can change your google background to one of our themes. It only will work on google.com websites",
    "icons": {
        "16": "/icons/icon1.png",
        "48": "/icons/icon2.png",
        "128": "/icons/icon3.png"
    },

    "author": "Stephan Teig",

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches":["https://www.google.com/*"],
            "css": ["main.css"]
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the main.css script

```
html body {
    background: url(https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/1554103.jpg);
}
```

I tried to make an extenion and expected the /* to work

Comment: You probably use Opera browser, which forbids extensions to modify the search page. You can allow it in the options of the extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm no because it is when you have searched something the background is either dar kmode or light mode and I want that to change because of the extension.. and also I am using google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, first, I added google.com/search as one website on the .json file and then I made my chrome light mode and it works but it does not look good... because it doesn't change the header that google has. but it technically works now.